Incomplete definition of smooth map between manifolds?
I'm reading Liang's book on Differential Geometry and in that the definition of a smooth map b/w two smooth manifolds is this:
Let $M,N$ be two smooth manifolds with dimensions $m,n$ respectively. Let $f:M\to N$ be a continuous map. For all $p\in M$, choose any coordinate system $(O_{\alpha},\psi_{\alpha})$ such that $p\in O_{\alpha}$, and coordinate system $(O'_{\beta},\psi'_{\beta})$ such that $f(p)\in O'_{\beta}$. Then $\psi'_{\beta}\circ f\circ\psi_{\alpha}^{-1}$ is a map from $\psi_{\alpha}[O_{\alpha}]$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$. If all of these $n$ functions of $m$ variables are smooth, then $f$ is smooth.
Just to be sure, there's an additional condition, right? That $f(O_{\alpha})\subseteq O'_{\beta}$? If this condition is implicit in the above explanation, I can't see it..

That would be correct, yes. The version available from springer adds "...is a map from $V_\alpha = \psi_\alpha[O_\alpha]$ (or an open subset of $V_\alpha$)" which accounts for this, so it's likely an oversight.

It's entirely my oversight then. That bracket phrase is available in my version also, but in a hurry I didn't type it out. Sorry about that. But I still don't get why that phrase would imply that $f(O_{\alpha})\subseteq O'_{\beta}$

I doesn't, but rather solves the problem another way: Observe that $f(O_\alpha \cap f^{-1}(O'\beta)) \subseteq O'\beta$, so all you need to do is to restrict to $\psi_\alpha(O_\alpha \cap f^{-1}(O'_\beta))$ and you're done :)

@BenSteffan: Sorry for the late reply. So in that case, can't we relax the condition for a map to be smooth like so: $f$ is smooth if for every point $p\in M$, there is a chart $(O_{\alpha}, \psi_{\alpha})$ at $p$ and a chart $(O'{\beta}, \psi'{\beta})$ at $f(p)$ such that $S\equiv f(O_{\alpha})\cap O'{\beta}$ is non-empty (provided that $f(p)\in S$)? Since in that case there would be some non-trivial intersection of $f^{-1}(O'{\beta})$ and $O_{\alpha}$, and we can restrict $f$ to that intersection

...and $\psi'\beta \circ f \circ \psi\alpha^{-1}$ suitably restricted is smooth. But if you say that $O_\alpha$ is a chart around $p$ and $O'\beta$ is a chart around $f(p)$ the condition on $S$ is vacuous: it's automatically non-empty since it contains $f(p)$ by definition. So basically there's two ways to go about it: Either require that $f(O\alpha) \subseteq O'\beta$ or restrict $f$ to $O\alpha \cap f{-1}(O'_\beta)$. These are equivalent since restrictions of coordinate charts to open subsets are again coordinate charts.
